# Devise, use lockable by code

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

Devise has nice feature called `:locakble`. It locks when user has failed to login multiple times and sends email to recover it.

All of them works when I use webpages with Devise.

How to check password, make failed attempts and lock my user by using **code**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call `lock_access!` on the model you registered devise for.

https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/lib/devise/models/lockable.rb#L40

Comment: Well this makes it very hard for me to guess how your users enter passwords at all

Comment: Please consider that I somehow got their password.